# Check if a cat and subCat exist in two different table using a single sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables...

```
#mainCats
catId | catName
----------------
1     | Furniture
2     | Cutlery

#subCats
subCatId | subCatName | catId | catName 
-------------------------------------
1     | Tables        | 1     | Furniture
2     | Chairs        | 1     | Furniture
3     | Knives        | 2     | Cutlery
```

When adding items to a third table - items, I need check if a valid category and subcategory exist.

The way the data comes in right now, is like this:

```
http://www.example.com/additem/?cat=1&sub=2&add=Table_Lamps
```

And the way it's done is like this. **This is just a stripped down example.**

```
1st:
Select count(catId) as hasCat from mainCats where catId=1
if(hasCat == 1)
{

Select count(subCatId) as hasSubCat from subCats where subCatId=2 and catId=1;
if(hasSubCat == 1)
{
 //Do the adding to the table here

}else{
 echo 'A subCategory was not found';
} 


}else{
 echo 'A category was not found';
}
```

Is there a good way to check if a cat and subcat exist in one single step rather that all this much of code.

This thing comes from an old site from 1998.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept of providing a more generic error message like `Category or subcategory not found`, then you can skip the first select.  You could even skip both select: assuming that the third table has foreign keys pointing to catId and subcatId, you can perform the insert without any check, catching exceptions to understand whether cat or subcat is missing.

If you need to distinguish the two error cases, you can perform the second select before the first one: if the second select succeds you don't need to execute the first one, if the second select fails (no category) you execute the first one to understand whether at least the main category exists.  In this way, assuming that in most cases categories exist, you avoid 50% of queries.  Again, you could also perform the insert without any check, catch exceptions and the perform the first select to understand whether at least the main category exists.  In this way you avoid almost all queries but you can still distinguish the two error cases.

Of course I'm assuming that you goal is to reduce queries for better efficiency, not to remove some line of code.

Comment: @Norman: ok, in this case you have no FK, so you cannot perform inserts without manually checking for data integrity, but you can still reduce the number of queries as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(mc.catId) AS hasCat COUNT(subCatId) AS hasSubCat FROM mainCats mc
LEFT JOIN subCats
WHERE subCatId=2 AND catId=1;
```

This will give you work if you have matching rows in neither table, or in both tables, or if you have a matching row in `mainCats`, but not in `subCats`.

The third option, (row in `subCats` but not in `mainCats`) won't show with this query.

If **MySQL** had `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you could get all four options in one query.

Interestingly, **Microsoft SQL Server** has `FULL OUTER JOIN`, while **Oracle** and **MySQL** don't.

I learned Microsoft SQL Server first, and then I took a university course that taught Oracle. When we learned about joins, the prof only explained `CROSS`, `INNER`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT`. So I asked about `FULL` join, and she asked me why would I ever need it. I gave her several examples I from work where I had used FULL joins, and she insisted that was just bad database design...

I then did some research on my own and was shocked to realize that Oracle didn't have full joins. When I started using MySQL, I was just slightly disappointed, but not shocked to discover it doesn't have full joins either.